Is $(A_1 \cap B) \cup (A_2 \cap B^c) = A_1 \cap A_2$?
This is not a statement from some book or something. It just came up while I was working on something else, so it's only my intuition that tells me that
$$(A_1 \cap B) \cup (A_2 \cap B^c) = A_1 \cap A_2$$
I could not prove it formally, but I feel intuitively it should hold because I do intersect two sets that contain $B$ and $B^c$ but the contribution of $B$ and $B^c$ in the intersection should be zero. But I am not sure how to prove it (if it holds).

Consider $A_1=[0,1[$, $A_2=]1,2]$ and $B=[0,2]$.

Venn diagrams are another way to look at this sort of question.

It's true $A_1 \cap A_2$ must be a subset of $(A_1\cap B)\cup(A_2\cap B^c)$  (if $a \in \A_1\cap A_2$ then $a$ is in both $A_1$ and $A_2$ if $a\in B$ then $a\in A_1\cap B$ and if not $a\in A_2\cap B$. But $(A_1\cap B)\cup (A_2\cap B^c)$ is clearly not a subset of $A_1\cap A_2$. If $a\in A_1\cap B$ there is no reason to assume it is also in $A_2$. Likewise if $a\in A_2\cap B^c$ there is no to assume it is also in $A_1$.

Let $A_1$ be even numbers. $A_2$ be multiples of $3$ and $B$ be multiples of $5$.  $A_1 \cap A_2$ will be multiples of $6$.  $A_1\cap B$ will be multiples of $10$ and $A_2\cap B^2$ will be multiples of $3$ that are not also multiples of $5$.  $(A_1\cap B)\cup (A_2\cap C^2)$  will by all multiples of $10$ and all multiples of $3$ that aren't multiples of $5$. This will include all multiples of $6$ (whether a multiple of $5$ or not) but also will include multiples of $10$ that aren't multiples of six and add multiples of $3$ that are div by $5$ as well.

I came up with the example by considering $A_1, A_2, B$ to be sets in which elements shared and not shared will be even distributed.   Becase clear elements of one of th A_i$ but not the other but in B (if 1) or not in B (if 2) would be included in one side but not the other.  Multiples of primes is a good way to get thorough distribution.

Here it is a counter-example. Consider $A_{1} = \{1\}$, $A_{2} = \{2\}$ and $B = \{1\}$.

The shaded area is $(A_1 \cap B) \cup (A_2 \cap B^c)$, which is different from $A_1 \cap A_2$. The latter is 'missing' $(A_1 \cap B \cap A_2^c) \cup (A_2 \cap B^c \cap A_1^c) $.


There are two things that should set off alarm bells.  1) the expression on the right has nothing to do with $B$ and 2) the expression on the right restricts itself to the intersection of $A_1$ and $A_2$ but on the left, which is a union, there is nothing to restrict us to elements that that are in both.
About $B$.  The elements of $B$ only interact with $A_1$ on the left, and $B^c$ only with $A_1$.  There is no consideration of the elements of $A_1$ that are not in $B$ or the elements of $A_2$ that are.  I think your confusion might be that on the right hand side we are only considering the intersection of $A_1$ and $A_2$ so if we have an element of $A_1$ not in $B$ it will also be in $A_2$.  But that's not valid because we are trying to prove just that the elements on the right hand side are in the left hand side, but also that the elements NOT on the right hand side are NOT on the left hand side.
About $\cap$.  here's the thing.  The left hand side includes $A_1 \cup B$.  So  that includes all the elements of $A_1$ and $B$ that are not in $A_2$.  Those are on the left hand side but not the right hand side. It also includes all the elements in $A_2$ that are not in $B$ but are not in $A_1$.
So to get a counter example we just need to consider the element $x$ is is $A_1$ and $B$ but not $A_2$.  The element $y$ is in $A_2$ but not $A_1$ nor $B$.
We can do that with $A_1=\{x\}, A_2=\{y\}, B=\{x\}$ and $U=\{x,y\}$.
Then $B^c= \{y\}$ and $(A_1\cap B)\cup (A_2\cap B)=\{x\}\cup \{y\} = \{x,y\}$.  But $A_1 \cap A_2 = \emptyset$.
We can make this more colorful if we want: add elements in $A_1$ and $A_2$ not in $B$, say $z$; add elements in $A_1$ and $A_2$ in $B$, say $w$. An element in $A_1$ but not $B$, say $v$. And an element in $A_2$ and $B$, say $u$ so....
$A_2=\{x,z,w,v\}, A_2=\{y,z,w,u\}$ and $B=\{x,w,u\}$ then.... $B^c=\{z,y,v\}$
$(A_1 \cap B)\cup (A_2\cap B^c)=\{x,w\}\cup \{y,z\}=\{x,w,y,z\}$ but $A_1\cap A_2=\{w,z\}$.
